# Is there a way to get the rotation of a videosphere?

Tags: aframe

In A-Frame. I need to output the roll, pitch and yaw as I move the view of `<a-videosphere>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `document.querySelector('a-videosphere').getAttribute('rotation')`. The result will be a `{x, y, z}` object in degrees.

If you want the direct `THREE.Vector3` object in radians, you can do `document.querySelector('a-videosphere').object3D.rotation`.